# Excel Interop AutoFilter by Date

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a Windows Forms Application (Framework 4.6.1) that uses Microsoft Office Interop to open and manipulate an Excel worksheet. I need to set a filter for a specific date. My app needs to work with different date formats.

[image]

I have a property defined like bellow. This property returns valid dates in the range 01/01/2014 - 01/01/2019

```
protected DateTime CurrentFileDate 
{ 
   get 
   {
      // Some implementation to retrieve a date 
   }
}
```

**I am trying to set an AutoFilter on a date column using a date value (not a string)**:

```
var ws = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
var r = ws.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range;
r.AutoFilter(3, CurrentFileDate.ToOADate());
```

This approach doesn't work as Excel is interpreting the value as a double and none of the rows match the filter.

`r.AutoFilter(3, CurrentFileDate);` doesn't work as it interprets the date as a string (which doesn't necessarily match the date format used by excel)

Any ideas on how to set that filter?

Comment: Please let me know what is the value "CurrentFileDate' you are passing and if any more details on how excel data looks like?

Comment: CurrentFileDate has a date in 2014-2018

Comment: Just trying to understand more - The excel screen shot you mentioned has same date format but the question talks about multiple formats in the excel date. So I am assuming the dates in the excel will have different date formats? Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @MaheshB yes. In this case they are dd/MM/yyyy but they could also be dd/MMM or MMMM dd

Comment: OH! I got what you mean. No, there are no mixed formats in the same excel worksheet, all the dates should (theoretically) be in the same format, but different workbooks could have different date formats.